# What to use on this occasion to save the value of a variable

Tags: java

I need to create a variable in a method to store a quantity of records from a result set when I do a check to login and then I would set that value to that variable, my question is I have a singleton to save the data my database the best way to save this value would be a singleton?

Taking into account that this is my method:

```
String verStatus = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM equipment_requisition";
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement (verStatus);
ResultSet rsStatus = stmt.executeQuery ();
rsStatus.next ();
int Result = rsStatus.getInt (1);
```

This method is still incomplete but I need to do a check:

With the value of the variable I want to save after logging in:
With this variable Result of my method, to make an alert using the TimerTask.

In other words, is there a more correct way to use the singleton since I need to modify the value of this variable in my method?

Comment: There is no singleton in your code.

Comment: I did not post my singleton I was wondering if the singleton is the best way to use this case

Comment: Because I will have to set this value whenever there is a change in the amount of database records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear, but if I understand you correctly you want to retrieve the result from the statement execution i.e is the number of equipment acquisition.If am correct, I would u return the result from a method that u can always call when u login.

Comment: Sorry, my english is horrible, I'm using a translator.

Comment: Well I was wondering which is the best option to use a singleton or use another way to save this variable to use in all screens of the program

ie when I log in I save the total amount of registration and have a timertask every 10 minutes that will check
the value of this query made when you were logged in
and with the value of a new query

Comment: So I wanted to know the best way to pick up and set this value
would it be singleton?

Comment: Yes, singleton would be fine as this is scenario of a shared instance